# Get count from data-* attribute does not work, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the `data-count` property each time I click in a given `th` and below is how I am doing it. For some reason the value of `data_id` is always `undefined` and I am not able to find why. Must be something really silly.

What I am missing here?

```js
$(".s_header").click(function() {
    var column_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var data_id = $('#' + column_id).data('count');

    console.log(column_id);
    console.log(data_id);

    if (data_id % 2 == 0) {
        console.log("Even");
    } else {
        console.log("odd");
    }

    $('#' + column_id).data('count', data_id + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="s_grid" width="100%">
    <tr class="header hover" style="">
        <th id="col_1" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 1</th>
        <th id="col_2" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 2</th>
        <th id="col_3" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 3</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're getting the id of `$(this)` and searching for the element corresponding to the extracted id, which is `$(this)`?

Comment: @Phiter not sure what you are asking there, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `.data()` didn't work, but you can simplify your code by using `this.dataset`, since `.data()` will store the value in the jQuery's global object, instead of updating the dom.

```js
$(".s_header").click(function() {
    var count = parseInt(this.dataset.count);
    console.log(count % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd");
    this.dataset.count++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="s_grid" width="100%">
    <tr class="header hover" style="">
        <th id="col_1" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 1</th>
        <th id="col_2" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 2</th>
        <th id="col_3" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 3</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your jQuery version. From the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2):

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5 specification.

Switching your snippet to 1.4.3 instead of 1.4.1 fixes the issue so that `.data('count')` returns `'0'`. Note that you still have a typo when *setting* the data (you're using `.data('counter', ...)` instead of `.data('count', ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

`.data()` is only available in version 1.4.3 or newer. Either update your jquery version or use `.attr("data-count")`

```js
$(".s_header").click(function() {
    var column_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var data_id = $('#' + column_id).attr('data-count');

    console.log(column_id);
    console.log(data_id);

    if (data_id % 2 == 0) {
        console.log("Even");
    } else {
        console.log("odd");
    }

    $('#' + column_id).data('counter', data_id + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="s_grid" width="100%">
    <tr class="header hover" style="">
        <th id="col_1" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 1</th>
        <th id="col_2" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 2</th>
        <th id="col_3" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 3</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `var data_id = $('#' + column_id).attr('data-count');` instead.

```js
$(".s_header").click(function() {
    var column_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var data_id = $('#' + column_id).attr('data-count');

    console.log(column_id);
    console.log(data_id);

    if (data_id % 2 == 0) {
        console.log("Even");
    } else {
        console.log("odd");
    }

    $('#' + column_id).data('counter', data_id + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="s_grid" width="100%">
    <tr class="header hover" style="">
        <th id="col_1" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 1</th>
        <th id="col_2" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 2</th>
        <th id="col_3" data-count="0" class="s_header">Col 3</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The lookup is unnecessary.  The id lookup is finding the element that was just clicked.